# what's the meaning of (base->*&Func)() in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, vtable

Here's simple class definitions like

```
class Base{
    public:
        virtual void Func(){
            cout<<"Func in Base"<<endl;
        }
 };

 class Derived : public Base{
     public:
         virtual void Func(){
             cout<<"Func in Derived"<<endl;
         }
 }

 Base *b = new Derived();
```

and the statement

```
 (b->*&Base::Func)();
```

calls the Derived version of Func, different from b->Base::Func() which calls the base version as expected, why this happened and what's the meaning of that call exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointers to virtual member functions. How does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087600/pointers-to-virtual-member-functions-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 5):

The meaning of the call is to add verbosity.  Basically: the
expression `&Base::Func` is a pointer to member function, and
`(b->*x)()` is the syntax for calling the member function
pointed to by `x` on the object pointed to by `b`.  In this
case, since `x` is a constant, it's about the same as writing
`*&variable`.  It means the same as `b->Func()`.

As to why it behaves differently from `b->Base::Func`, it's 
because the `Base::Func` are operands to the `&` operator, where
the `Base::` has a somewhat different role.  If you'd written:

```
void (Base::*pmf)() = &Base::Func;
```

and called

```
(b->*pmf)();
```

you'd expect the virtual function to be called correctly.  All
the expression you've posted does is replace the variable `pmf`
with a constant.

Answer (score 3):

```
&Base::Func
```

Means "take the address of the function `Func` in `Base`".

As it is a virtual function, it is not a simple function pointer, but actually stores the index into the virtual function table.

By then calling this with `->*`, which means "derefence and access this member", you get the function at that index in `b`'s virtual table, which is the `Derived` version. So it is basically the same as `b->Func()`.

Why would someone do this? I have no idea!

I have explained a little about member function pointers previously, [here (with pictures!)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12006882/1171191).

Comment: smells like an interview question